# How should I use PHPDoc to document that a method "doesn't throw"?

Tags: php, exception, phpdoc

The below class is a contrived example of what I am referring to. The `get` method in this class will throw an exception if an incorrect id is passed to it, which is documented in it's phpdoc block. The other two methods `getApple` & `getBanana` will never cause an exception to be thrown because we *know* that these IDs exist.

Unfortunately PHPStorm will still complain about an unhandled exception, and adding a `@throws` tag to these methods almost seems like we're lying because there is no possible way that they will throw the exception.

Is there any way to document this scenario?

**Example class**

```php
class Fruit
{

    const APPLE  = 1;
    const BANANA = 2;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getApple(): string
    {
        return $this->get(self::APPLE);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBanana(): string
    {
        return $this->get(self::BANANA);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $fruitId
     * @return string
     * @throws FruitNotFoundException
     */
    public function get($fruitId): string
    {
        switch ($fruitId) {
            case self::APPLE:
                return 'Apple!';
            case self::BANANA:
                return 'Banana!';
            default:
                throw new FruitNotFoundException();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `getApple()` and `getBanana()` use `$this->get()` method that could throw an Exception, therefore using any of these methods could result in throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However there is no possible way that those methods will ever throw an exception because we can see the path of the code. The IDs they are passing are correct.

Comment: There is a possibility to throw an exception, for example when you change the ID that is passed to `get()`, or maybe if one of the cases is removed from the `switch`. I agree that in the current state no exception will be thrown, but `@throws` indicates that there are circumstances under which an exception could be thrown. Remember that you can provide a description to describe those circumstances.